# How many pokemon are obtainable in XY

Tags: pokemon-x-y

How many pokemon are **legitimately** obtainable in Pokemon X and Y? I'm talking about only these 6th gen games and by legitimately I mean by catching, breeding and trading **only** between those two games (no pokebank, hacking or events).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

125 from older games are not obtainable in X/Y. Also you can't get [Diancie](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Diancie). So you can get 593 Pokémon from the 719 in all.

You can take a look here which Pokémon are only available at a speciffic version: [Pokemon X](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pokemon_X)

Pokémon which are not available in X/Y (in German): [not in Pokémon X/Y](http://www.pokewiki.de/Pok%C3%A9mon_X_und_Pok%C3%A9mon_Y#Editionsspezifische_Pok.C3.A9mon_und_Mega-Steine)